# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value:

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm having some problems while using PDO. It all seems correct but I am getting this error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: ':permissao' for column 'permissao' at row 1\n
```

Here's the code that prints the output

```
$this->nome = $nome;
    $this->email = $email;


    $salt = $this->generateSalt();
    $permissao = 10;
            $activo = 0;
    #encripta chama a funcao para encriptar a password do utilizador
    $this->password = $this->pwdEncript($password, $salt);

 $params = array('nome'=>$this->nome,
                            'email'=>  $this->email, 
                            'password'=>  $this->password,
                            'salt'=>$salt,
                            'permissao'=>$permissao,
                            'activo'=>$activo);


    $sql = "INSERT INTO sys_users(nome,email,password,salt,permissao,activo)
                VALUES(':nome',':email',':password',':salt',':permissao',':activo')";       


    try
    {   
        $sth = $this->db->prepare($sql); 
                    $sth->execute($params);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo 'Erro ao inserir na base de dados'.$e->getMessage().'\n';
    }
```

Permissao is an INT on mysql table.

Glad for any help given on this one ;)

Comment: What's the value of $permissao?

Comment: @PeeHaa if I cast to int, I get the same result. 
I've updated the code. It's basicaly an numeric value from 1 to 10.

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion it's the quotes you're putting around all the parameter placeholders.  As prepared statements escape the inserted strings for you anyway, you don't need them and it's possible they're causing you trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO sys_users(nome,email,password,salt,permissao,activo)
        VALUES(:nome,:email,:password,:salt,:permissao,:activo)";
```

Comment: Working like a charm! Thanks a lot! I'd loose days before i'd try that out.

Answer (score 3):

Already said it in the comments, but it looks like you don't need the quotes around the placeholders.  Just rely on the Prepared Statement mechanism to do it for you.

NOTE: For MySQL, PDO defaults to emulating prepared statements.  For extra security you might want to set it up to use real prepared statements instead.

```
$pdo -> setAttribute (PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```